# На вотчине / в вотчине

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно говорить: ***на** вотчине* или ***в** вотчине*?

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[ВО́ТЧИНА](http://www.endic.ru/kuzhecov/Votchina-56447.html), -ы; ж.

1. В России до 18 в.: родовое наследственное земельное владение.
2. *Разг.* О месте, территории, предприятии и т. п., где кто-либо чувствует себя полновластным хозяином. *Завод — его вотчина.*

Вот что нашлось в НКРЯ:
[в вотчине](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&endyear=2019&nodia=1&p=0) — 92; в своей вотчине —32; [на вотчине](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5) — 6.

Если в контексте используется слово в первом значении, то нужен предлог "в" — **в вотчине** (в имении, во владении, в поместье).

В вотчине Сергей Львович никогда не бывал и болезненно морщился, когда матушка намекала ― не без яду, ― что не мешало бы, дескать, заглянуть. [Ю. Н. Тынянов. Пушкин (1935-1943)]

Если же подразумевается второе значение, то, я думаю, возможны оба предлога — в зависимости от того, что является вотчиной (в вотчине — в школе; на вотчине — на земле, на заводе).

Comment: *Если в контексте используется слово в первом значении, то нужен предлог "в" — в вотчине (в имении, во владении, в поместье).* - А как же примеры из нацкорпуса?  Два последних как минимум.

Comment: [А. Е. Зарин. Двоевластие (1912)]: в вотчине — 9 примеров; на вотчине — только 4. Один из героев говорит: _Скучно **на Москве** мне, матушка..._ Отсюда вполне возможно и "на вотчине". Не все же "шибко грамотные", даже если их царь хочет в дворцовые взять.

Comment: Вообще-то я не спрашивал, сколько там примеров на какой вариант. Вопрос в том, как оценить имеющиеся примеры с "на", исходя из вашего категорического утверждения, что в таких случаях нужно только "в".